# Find the pointwise limit of the function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx, & \quad 0 \leq x <\frac{1}{n} \\ 2-nx & \quad \frac{1}{n} \leq x <\frac{2}{n} \\0 & \quad x \geq \frac{2}{n}\end{cases}$$

Attempt $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for each $x \in [0,\infty)$ since there is an integer $N$ such that $x \geq \frac{2}{N}$ then $n \geq N \implies f_n(x)=0$

is this attempt correct at finding and justifying the pointwise limit?

Comment: Almost. You need to separate the trivial case $x=0$ since it is not greater than any $\frac2N$. However at $x=0$ the pointwise limit is also zero.

Comment: @player3236 at $x=0$ $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for all $n \geq 1$?

Comment: $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$

Comment: Check your negation of definition again. You need show for every $N$, for some combination of $n>N$ and $x$, $|f(x) - f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon$. Besides $f_1(5) = 0 = f(5)$.

Comment: @player3236 For the negation would this be okay?Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ for any $N \in\mathbb{N}$ with $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and $n>N \implies  |f(\frac{1}{n})-f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})|=1>\frac{1}{2}=\epsilon$?

Comment: Splendid. That's it.